# Looking for an example/tutorial for using P2PMessageQueue Class from the Smart Device Framework

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce, ipc, smart-device-framework

I have to use Interprocess Communication in a Windows CE Project but I hve no experience with this. What I found out is, that the Smart Device Framework has a wrapper Class for the P2PMessageQueue Class but I don't know how to use this one to communicate between to running Applications and how to send Objects between them.
Does someone have a small example or Tutorial on how to implement and use this class to exchange Objects between to running Applications on the same Windows CE Device?

Thank you

twickl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [an example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446556.aspx).

Comment: But this does not use the Smart Device Framework?!

Comment: It's the exact same class - just reference teh SDF and use it's version. In fact the SDF version has a couple of bug fixes from the MSDN version.